# why You can't use `blank space ' after \the

Tags: latex-base

If I define

```
\newcount\punkt
\def\newpt{\the\punkt\space\advance\punkt by 1}
```

everything runs fine; but if I do

```
\newcounter{punkt}
\newcommand\newpt{\the\punkt\space\stepcounter{\punkt}}
```

I get

```
You can't use `blank space  ' after \the.
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The analog to Plain's `\the\punkt` in LaTeX would be

```
\the\csname c@punkt\endcsname
```

because when processing `\newcounter{punkt}` LaTeX does

```
\newcount\c@punct
```

Note the big difference: after `\newcount` (which is borrowed from plain TeX) there should be a control sequence name, whereas the argument to `\newcounter` is a string of characters that will be used to build different control sequences, namely

```
\c@punkt
\thepunkt
\p@punkt
```

The first one is the name of the allocated count register, the second one is the macro for the representation of the counter's value (by default `\arabic{punkt}`) and the last one is the “prefix” when processing a `\label` linked to this counter (see `source2e` for details). In particular, `\newcounter{punkt}` does *not* define `\punkt`.

So with `\newcounter{punkt}` and `\the\punkt` you get an error about an undefined control sequence (unless `\punkt` *is* independently defined) and if you press return at the error message, or if TeX is run in “nonstop” mode by a front-end, TeX ignores the undefined control sequence and proceeds to apply `\the` to the next token; since `\space` is expandable, TeX expands it and tries to apply `\the` to the resulting token list, but `\the<space token>` is illegal.

Always look at the *first* error message. And use `\thepunkt` instead.

Comment: therefore: `\thepunkt` instead of `\the\punkt` did fix the error.

Comment: @jarnosz That's right.

Comment: your clairvoyance gave you the tick...

Answer (score 6):

The code you posted, if used, generates a different error to the one you show.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{punkt}

\newcommand\newpt{\the\punkt\stepcounter{\punkt}}


\begin{document}
\newpt

\end{document}
```

---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\newpt ->\the \punkt 
                     \stepcounter {\punkt }
l.9 \newpt
          
?
```

The latex command `\newcounter` does not define `\punkt`, you can use `\thepunkt` to get the print form.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{punkt}

\newcommand\newpt{\thepunkt\stepcounter{punkt}}


\begin{document}

\newpt

\newpt

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can generate the error shown using a construct such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\x{\noexpand\the\space}\x


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

---

```
! You can't use `blank space  ' after \the.
\x ->\the  
            
l.3 \edef\x{\noexpand\the\space}\x
                                        
?
```

Comment: FWIW, `\newcommand\newpt{\the\punkt\space\stepcounter{\punkt}}` does give the claimed error in Overleaf as the second error of six.

Comment: @Teepeemm if you are brave enough to scroll past an error random unexpected behaviour should be expected:-)

Comment: I run LaTeX in nonstopmode; the first exclamation mark was the one I reported, not the previous error.

Comment: @jarnosz as you did not post any code that gives an error I can't really comment.

Comment: I was just trying to say that I ignored (very much like my LaTeX run) the first error, and flagged only the second...

Comment: @jarnosz I read your comment as saying the opposite, but always with TeX ignore all errors after the first, if you scroll past an error tex's "recovery", as here, will generate multiple spurious errors.

Comment: wilco, and out!